# scala try/catch not catching some exceptions

Tags: scala, exception, try-catch

Unless the try/catch doesn't work the why I think it should work, I'd expect the following exception be caught. Instead it just throws NPE.

```
try {
  scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(null)
} catch {
  case e:Throwable => println("oh cr*p!")
}
```

In contrast, the following code does work.

```
try {
  1/0
} catch {
  case e:Throwable => println("oh cr*p")
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`io.Source` is lazy, thus does not evaluate its input, until it is needed. Therefore the exception is not thrown when it is initialized, but when it is used for the first time. This example shows that:

```
scala> class Foo(val x: io.Source)
defined class Foo

scala> new Foo(io.Source.fromInputStream(null))
res2: Foo = Foo@1c79f780
```

No exception here. But as soon, as you use it (in this case to print it to the console) it throws an exception:

```
scala> res2.x
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:129)
```

And a little tip: don't catch throwables, because that will also catch things like `StackOverflowError` and `OutOfMemoryError`, which you don't want to be catched.

Comment: why shouldn't we catch throwables like StackOverflowError?

Comment: Because a stack overflow is always an error in the program and instead of treating the symptom, you should remove the cause.